# Manga where a boy can become a ghost every time he sleeps, and finds a girl who can do the same

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for a supernatural and ecchi manga where a boy can become a ghost every time he sleeps. He finds a girl who can do the same, and she helps him learn about his new powers. The boy travels around his whole city as a ghost and sees a girl that is also flying around like a ghost, since they can go through walls and such. He also sees his crush getting banged lol. Any tip or information is gladly appreciated. Very important the MC is a boy his ability only works once he falls asleep

Comment: Welcome to the site. If someone correctly identifies the manga you're thinking of, please upvote that answer and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Is it [Yuutai Nova](https://myanimelist.net/manga/11036/Yuutai_Nova)?

> A young man who discovers he can have out of body experiences, which he uses at first to have fun but quickly leads him to discover that his life isn't what he thought it was, and people he knows have lives he never imagined. And then he meets this girl who has the same power and much more control...

Comment: Seems like this could be the right answer, but in future, please don't link to sites that have full comics available to read for free, as that creates potential legal issues for this site. I've replaced your link with one from [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/). [MangaUpdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/index.html) and [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/) are also good sites to link to.

Comment: Sorry, I just clicked on the first link that came up! Found with a search for "manga astral projection" which led to someone asking a similar question on reddit.

Comment: No worries; I made the same mistake myself in the past, before I was corrected by a more experienced user.

Answer (score 1):

This might be [Yajin](https://myanimelist.net/manga/114284/Yajin) by Uru Okabe:

> Onda Iko, a solitary schoolgirl, can see ghosts. Which is somewhat annoying since one has been occupying her room for some time now and hindering her sleep. Things get even more complicated when she finds out two of her classmates can leave their bodies and wander around—a result of a mysterious online channel called 'The Night Ones'—and starts encountering more dangerous things than just pesky apparitions in her room.

Comment: Henning Kockerbeck nope not the manga I am looking for but thank you nonetheless